# Webpack Dev Server Error: Invariant Violation: Minified React error #200

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I get the title error in the browser console as it tries to load an index.html file with a script tag to the bundle.js file. I jut completed the tutorial which pointed to /dist with its own index.html and a compiled main.js file so I don't understand why my own bundle.js receives a minification related error:

```
react-dom.production.min.js:13 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Minified React error #200; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=200 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings. 
    at http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:22:420
    at o (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:22:523)
    at Object.render (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:22:104077)
    at Module.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:6:1229)
    at P (http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:1:7211)
    at http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:1:8035
    at http://localhost:8080/bundle.js:1:8043
(anonymous) @   react-dom.production.min.js:13
o   @   react-dom.production.min.js:14
render  @   react-dom.production.min.js:266
(anonymous) @   index.jsx:16
P   @   bootstrap:726
(anonymous) @   bootstrap:793
(anonymous) @   bootstrap:793
```

Anyone know what the issue is? My webpack.config.js is below:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const dotenvWebpack = require("dotenv-webpack");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry : {
    './adminSettingsArea' :
      './adminSettingsArea/src/index.jsx'
  },
  output : {
    filename : '[name]/bundle.js',
    path : path.resolve(__dirname),
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer : {
    "contentBase" : './adminSettingsArea',
    "hot" : true
  },
  plugins : [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new dotenvWebpack()
  ],
  module : {
    rules : [
      {
        test : /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude : [/node_modules/, /vendor/],
        use : {
          loader : "babel-loader",
          options : {
            presets : [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              "@babel/preset-react"
            ]
          },
        }
      }
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: So error message contains a link https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=200 There you can see something's wrong with your init code and target container you're trying render to cannot be found

Comment: Looks like I forgot to setup a div to inject into. Works now, thank you!

Comment: @SeanD can u pls help here what needs to add here. what did u add to resolve this?